# PDF Viewer in JavaFX

Tags: java, pdf, javafx

I am using JavaFx-2.I need to view the pdf file in JavaFx. I searched in Google and found the below link.
http://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedalfx-viewer/

In this link I have created every thing whatever mentioned there and I am able to see `PdfHelpPanel` in Palette. When I drag this component to the `PDFHelpFrame` I am able to see the `fileLocations` property. Here I need to give the file locations but I don't know how to give the location of my pdf file. When I click browse in filelocations property it is asking for Custom Code, Default Editor, value from existing component. Which one I need to select. I am struck up exactly at 
http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/how-create-import-a-javabean-c-0

second image from last. If any one has done this already can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this project https://github.com/james-d/PdfViewer
It uses PDFRenderer library.